# How long are first generation Cloud SQL automated backups kept?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

How long are first generation Cloud SQL automated backups kept?  Google's [Overview of Backups](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery/backups?authuser=1) documentation makes no mention of this.  It says that the last 7 backups are kept but it does not mention when they are automatically deleted.  We have a project that hasn't been used much over the last year, and the last automated backup was on July 7. Today we noticed that backup was deleted so there are no backups at all. We'd like to know when they are deleted and is there any way to disable that in order to keep those backups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's response was to use the gcloud command line utility [gcloud sql backups list] instead of the admin console to see the list of backups. Google's response to that was "As you can see from the output of the gcloud command, the backups do exist all the way up to Oct 28, 2015. They have not been deleted. This is an issue with the console UI not displaying some of the old backups. We will get this fixed. Meanwhile, you can use the gcloud tool or the admin api to look at (or restore to) the old backups."

Answer (score 0):

Last 7 automated backups are kept as long as the instance is in valid state. Did you disable backups at any point? Can you send your instance name to cloud-sql@google.com?

Comment: Automated backups were never disabled. Binary logging is disabled, but that shouldn't matter. I sent the project id to that cloud-sql@google.com (there's only one sql instance for that project).